# Why these borders are showing when generating pdf using iTextsharp?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, itext

I am trying to generate multiple pdfs into a single pdf, which I have achieved by using itextSharp , but while generating them few thing I came across,which are pointed below:

- I am getting visible cell border just under image that i inserted .
- Bottom image taking a space which flicks the image into another page, with extra visible border.
- Also the paragraph didn't align to center.
- Apart from these I also need that the text(in paragraph)comes from view(this code is doing in MVC).

How to solve these errors? Below is my code:

```
public byte[] GetPDF(string pHTML)
    {
        byte[] bPDF = null;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        TextReader txtReader = new StringReader(pHTML);
        //Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(864.0f, 1152.0f);
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.NOTE);
        string path = Server.MapPath("PDFs");
        PdfWriter oPdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
        HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(doc);
        doc.Open();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {

                doc.NewPage();
                PdfPTable table= new PdfPTable(1);
                table.TotalWidth = 500f;
                table.LockedWidth = true;
                table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

                Image imageTopURL = Image.GetInstance("Top.PNG");
                       PdfPCell imgTopCell = new PdfPCell(imageTopURL);
                Paragraph p = new Paragraph("XYZ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 32f, Font.UNDERLINE));
                p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                table.AddCell(imgTopCell);
                table.AddCell(p);
                Image imageMidURL = Image.GetInstance("Mid.PNG");                    
                PdfPCell imgMidCell = new PdfPCell(imageMidURL);
                Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("ABC", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 29f, Font.ITALIC));
                p1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                table.AddCell(imgMidCell);
                imgMidCell.Border = 0;                 
                table.AddCell(p1);
                Image imageBotURL = Image.GetInstance("Bottom.PNG");
                PdfPCell imgBotCell = new PdfPCell(imageBotURL);
                table.AddCell(imgBotCell);
                imageTopURL.ScaleAbsolute(505f, 270f);
                imageMidURL.ScaleAbsolute(590f, 100f);
                imageBotURL.ScaleAbsolute(505f, 170f);
                 doc.Open();
                doc.Add(table);
                  htmlWorker.StartDocument();
                htmlWorker.Parse(txtReader);
                htmlWorker.EndDocument();
            }
              htmlWorker.Close();
               doc.Close();
        doc.Close();
        bPDF = ms.ToArray();
        return bPDF; 
}
```

Comment: What version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: Hi Amedee,I am using version 5.5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling the table that default cells shouldn't have a border:

```
table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
```

This means that `PdfPCell` instances that are created *implicitly* won't get a border. For instance: if you do:

```
table.AddCell("Implicit cell creation");
```

Then that cell won't get a border.

However: you are creating a cell *explicitly*:

```
PdfPCell imgTopCell = new PdfPCell(imageTopURL);
```

In this case, the `DefaultCell` is never used. It is very normal that `imgTopCell` has a border. If you don't want a border for `imgTopCell`, you need to define the `Border` of `imgTopCell` like this:

```
imgTopCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
```

Regarding the alignment: it seems that you didn't read about the difference between *text mode* and *composite* mode. Please read the documentation, for instance:

- [Why does ColumnText ignore the horizontal alignment?](http://itextpdf.com/question/why-does-columntext-ignore-horizontal-alignment)
- [How to right-align text in a PdfPCell?](http://itextpdf.com/question/how-right-align-text-pdfpcell)
- and many other FAQ entries about [text mode](http://itextpdf.com/tags/text-mode) and [composite mode](http://itextpdf.com/tags/composite-mode).

You are making a number of newbie mistakes that can all be fixed by reading the documentation. You have too many questions in one post. Please create new questions if my answer didn't solve every single of your problems. I see at least two more questions in your post (your question should actually be closed with as reason "Too broad").

**Update:**

In your comment, you added the following code snippet:

```
table.AddCell(new Paragraph(data.EmpName, new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 32f, Font.BOLD)));
```

You want to center this text.

First, let me explain that you are using the `AddCell()` method with a `Paragraph` as parameter. This doesn't really make sense as the `Paragraph` will be treated as a `Phrase`. You can as well write:

```
table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER ;
table.AddCell(new Phrase(data.EmpName, new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 32f, Font.BOLD)));
```

When you are passing a `Phrase` to the `AddCell()` method, you are

1. using **text mode** (the properties of the cell prevail over the properties of its elements), and
2. you are asking iTextSharp to create a `PdfPCell`.

In this case, iTextSharp will look at the `DefaultCell` and use the properties of that cell to create a new cell. If you want to center the content of that new cell, you need to define this at the level of the `DefaultCell`. All of this is explained in my answer to the following questions:

- [Why doesn't getDefaultCell().setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER) have any effect?](http://itextpdf.com/question/why-doesnt-getdefaultcellsetborderpdfpcellnoborder-have-any-effect)
- [What is the PdfPTable.DefaultCell property used for?](http://itextpdf.com/question/what-pdfptabledefaultcell-property-used)

Comment: Hello Bruno,I read about right-align text in PDF and changes according but still i am not getting the text into center . I have edited the code as :                          iTextSharp.text.Image imageT=iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath(ImgTopPath));
                PdfPCell imgTopCell = new PdfPCell(imageT);               
                imgTopCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
                imgTopCell.Border = 0;
                table.AddCell(imgTopCell);
                table.AddCell(new Paragraph(data.EmpName, new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 32f, Font.BOLD)));

Comment: @Chandan I've updated my answer. You shouldn't use comments to post code. As you can see, it is very hard to read code in a comment field.

Comment: Hello Bruno,I have done woth pdf generation and it is working fine on local  server,But when I am trying to run the smae code on server (a KInd of test server,used to test before deploying the code),it flicks an error : **Mailer Exception:Could not find file 'F:\IIS_Sites\Stackatest.xyz.com\Documents\Certificates **, I have tried few suggestion but never get the result ,so can you help again here?

Comment: @Chandan That problem is completely unrelated to the question above. hence I can not answer it here. Please post a new question and explain the problem in a better way, because in its current state nobody has a clue what you're talking about. We don't know anything about your `F:` drive, your IIS installation, nor about the `Certificates` directory you are referring to.

Comment: ,Thanks for suggestion,as I have posted a new question ,please have a look.